# How to write IGNORE query in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, insert

How to write below mysql query in Laravel query structure?

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO feeds(id, pubdate, title, description, link, author, location, feed_name,log_time) VALUES('$id','$pubDate','$title','$description','$link','$author','$feed_region','$feed_name',now())"));
```

Note: Must use IGNORE.

Comment: There is no such method in laravel query builder. you should use raw sqls.

Comment: `$numAffectedRows = DB::statement('INSERT IGNORE INTO feeds(id, ...) VALUES(?, ...)', [$id, ...]);`